# How to make a rounded drop shadow on a png image

Tags: css, filter, dropshadow

I am trying to recreate a website template I found on Behance.  While I found a great solution and learned something new with filter: dropshadow(); I would really like to just make the drop-shadow on my png rounded.  I tried border-radius changes but to no attest maybe blur() but that blurs the image, and I hoped you could do something like drop-shadow(blur()); which would be cheeky.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/KurkWeb/pen/YRWoqW) an image for clarity below and the code.  Thanks.

[image]

```
.weapon-1{

    background: url(../pictor/pistols/360fx360f.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #B3135D);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #B3135D);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #B3135D);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for rounded drop shadow you can use radial-gradient in background with transparent image.

original image used in snippet is [original image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/a/ae/250px-Captain_Falcon_SSB4.png)
Please refer snippet.

```css
body{background-color: black}
img {

    /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white, black, black);
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/a/ae/250px-Captain_Falcon_SSB4.png" />
</body>
```

Comment: Legit, I straight glanced over radial gradient.  Still this question could help someone else as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @StegnatSum ok...then please accept this answer. To help others in finding this as solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine elements for a really unique effect especially with compound colors.  Here I am using a blue and a purple.

```css
.weapon-1{
    background: url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/default_generated/weapon_hkp2000_aq_p2000_boom_light_large.39f01b0b86b795bea56300432fecfbf93415ee58.png) center center no-repeat,  radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #9C08E2 -100%, transparent 40%);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #2C18AF);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #2C18AF);
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #2C18AF);
}
```

```html
<div class="weapon weapon-1 mx-2"></div>
```